# How to onblur to get out of function

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have the following code which works perfectly but I need an onblur statement if a user clicks away from the dropdown, therefore taking it back to its original state - but have tried to implement this and have no idea where to begin really.

here's the code:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var choices = "<select class='choices'>"
                   +"<option value='Choice 1'>Choice 1</option>"
                   +"<option value='Choice 2'>Choice 2</option>"
                   +"<option value='Choice 3'>Choice 3</option>"
                   +"<option value='Choice 4'>Choice 4</option>"
                   +"</select>";

  $(".update").click(function() {
     var $this = $(this),
         currentChoice;
     // don't continue if there's already a select in this cell
     if ($this.find("select").length != 0)
        return;
     currentChoice = $this.html();
     var $choices = $(choices);
     $this.empty().append($choices);
     $choices.val(currentChoice);
  });

  $(document).on("change", ".choices", function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.parent().html($this.val());
     return false;
  });
});
</script>

<table id="list">
   <tr>
      <td>Film Name 1</td>
      <td class="update">Choice 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>File Name 2</td>
      <td class="update">Choice 3</td>
   </tr>
   <!-- etc -->
</table>
```

Also, can i then use `onchange="this.form.submit();"` to submit the change to my mysql db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case is bit tricky, from what I saw you have no choice but handle the global `click` event of the document, as the `blur` doesn't really work as expected for drop down element in my testings.

So in the global click event start a timer that reset the value and in the click event of the drop down itself and its parent cell cancel the timer so that the user can still select.

The code you have to add is:

```
var _timer = 0;       

$(document).on("click", ".choices, .update", function() {
    window.clearTimeout(_timer);
    return false;
});

$(document).click(function() {
    _timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        var oDDL = $(".choices");
        if (oDDL.length > 0)
            oDDL.parent().html(oDDL.val());
    }, 50);
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHMPh/).

**Edit**: in order to hide the previously opened drop down lists, you need to do that in the click event:

```
$(document).on("click", ".choices, .update", function() {
    window.clearTimeout(_timer);
    var curDDL = $(this);
    $(".choices").each(function() {
        if (this !== curDDL.get(0) && this !== curDDL.find("select").get(0))
            $(this).parent().html($(this).val());
    });
    return false;
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHMPh/1/).

Comment: many thanks for this, one final piece to the puzzle then, the user clicks away and this closes the event, thats great, can it also be made that if a user clicks Choice 2, it will close the event Choice 1? Basically meaning there can only ever be one select box open at a time - that i think would bring this to a close

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use onblur/onchange event in the input tags.. within the form element..

Comment: I know I can but how is the question... I'm guessing it would go in the select tag like onblur=***** buy what is the ***** thanks